# IF check seem to be checking wrongly

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement

I have made a game that is a typing game, I have a mode which only one word which works fine, but when I made a randomize mode it didn't seem to work when checking if the user has entered the correct sentence.

code and all necessary files are found here

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/SensibleJames/9730646)

can anyone suggest what I can do to fix this issue because it is really confusing me, as you can see I did a test when it tells me that the answer is incorrect by having it print out both the input of the user and the desired answer and they seem to match :|

Comment: You forgot to specify your input, internal state, and output.

Comment: What type is the element of words being looked up. I suspect it is not a string. But please provide more data, for instance how do you create the words list? Can you give an example entry from words and what the user has typed that do not match?

Comment: Your problem depends entirely on the contents of `words[wordloc]` and `answer`, yet you have not given us anything for these. How is `words` created? If `answer == word[wordloc]` is False, then the two values are *not* equal.

Comment: I love cleaning windows
I want to get the right stuff
You won't have what I got
It's simple, we kill the batman
and Jack said "It is not the beast in the man." these are all stored in a txt file that is read into the program and assigned to list

Comment: @SensibleJames, precision matters. Giving us a list of strings is much, much less useful than editing your question to include the actual code that assigns them.

Comment: is there any way I can upload all of the necessary files needed to run the program?

Comment: @SensibleJames ...and even that is less useful than modifying the code in such a way that it demonstrates the problem when run completely as-is -- which is to say, making it a SSCCE (see http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @SensibleJames, try making a gist (https://gist.github.com/) containing all those files. That way you can add and edit them with git, and anyone who wants to run your code can just do a git checkout to download all files of the gist. Though modifying your code to not *require* multiple files is rather strongly preferred -- see again the hints at sscce.org for suggestions on how to reduce the code you provide to the minimum amount needed to provide a reproducer.

Comment: sorry, this is my first time posting